# Clear a sequence in Nim

Tags: seq, nim-lang

What is the Nim equivalence of `List.Clear` in languages like java or c# for sequences? I see listed in system the proc `setLen`, but im not sure it does what i want. From the description:

`f the current length is greater than the new length, s will be truncated. s`

Does it mean everytime i set any seq len to 0 it will create a new instance of seq?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`setLen` resizes the `seq` without allocating a new one, so usually `x.setLen(0)` is fine. If you want to allocate a new `seq` and let the garbage collector clean up the old one, you can do `x = @[]` instead.